# Adb error while pulling an apk file from android device

Tags: android, apk, adb

I'm trying to extract .apk from my android device with adb. I tried this command :

```
adb shell pm path com.bitstrips.imoji
package:/data/app/com.bitstrips.imoji-1/base.apk
```

and

```
adb pull /data/app/com.bitstrips.imoji-1/base.apk
```

but I have an error "adb: error: remote object does not exist"

Comment: @Mohsen Yes same problem but no solutions

Comment: You need to make sure `base.apk` is there first. Then, make sure about the path (`com.bitstrips.imoji-1`) then try: `adb shell cat /data/app/com.bitstrips.imoji-1/base.apk > app.apk`